# How to fix an error in email confirmation using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to activate new user upon verification of email on new account creation.

This is a code-igniter problem and I am quite new to the framework. I am able to send confirmation email with the generated link + hash code to user. When a user clicks on the confirmation link, it returns a success message but does not update the database value from 0 => 1 and this triggers an error when user tries to login. I have used different approaches but none seem to work and i am wondering what i missed or why it isn't updating database value.

Here is my controller code:

```
 function verify() {

    $cid = $this->db->get_where('client' , array('client_id' => 
    $client_id))->row()->client_id; 
    $email = $this->db->get_where('client' , array('client_id' => 
    $client_id))->row()->email;
    $rhash = $this->db->get_where('client' , array('client_id' => 
    $client_id))->row()->hash;
    $result = array_merge($email,$rhash,$cid);

       if($email['hash'] == $rhash){  
           $this->crud_model->verify_user($email); 
           $this->session->set_flashdata('create_success', "Email 
      Verification Success. <br> Login to your account now and 
      complete your profile.");
           redirect(site_url('login'), 'refresh');
       }
       else{
          $this->session->set_flashdata('create_error', 'Email 
    Verification Failed. <br> Please retry, or confirm your 
    confirmation link.');
          redirect(site_url('login'), 'refresh');
       }       
    }
```

My Model:

```
 function verify_user($email) {
    $data = array('is_verified' => 1);
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->update('client', $data);
  }
```

I have used all of the declared variable just in case, but i am still not able to change "is_verified" to 1.

Comment: I really do need a pointer to this as I am just confused on what to do.

Comment: i think u just updated the whole other columns to null. can you verify?else have you tried using $this->db->set('is_verified', 1, FALSE) instead? ;

Comment: I was able to solve this by just modifying a few lines. You can't imagine the grin on my face right now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue just by modifying the model to these:

```
 function verify_user($email) {
    $data = $this->db->update('client', array(
        'is_verified' => 1
    ));
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
 }
```

Comment: I can't really say why the former did not work and why this one worked instead. If anyone can explain to me, I'd be grateful.